# Adding redundant nodes in a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

This is a program i've been working on. This program lets you put strings into a linked list and then lets you manipulate the list. "ins" lets you insert strings into the list, "del" lets you delete those strings, and "prl" lets you review what's in the list, and 'pst' lets you look at the print statistics. I think i've gotten a decent amount done, but here's my issue. I want there to be a # next to the node more than 1 node is printed in prl,

say you wanted to enter name 5 times into the list:

```
Command? ins name
Command? ins name
Command? ins name
Command? ins name
Command? ins name
Command? prl
name 1 
name 1
name 1
name 1 
name 1
```

Instead of 5 "name 1" I would like it to say "name 5" once,
I've tried a million different options in my ins function, my main method, and my if statement for ins. Nothing seems to change the output. If you have any advice or tips it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MIN_LENGTH 4
#define MAX_LENGTH 11 //define command length

struct node{
     char list[MAX_LENGTH];
     int count;
       struct node *next;
}; //creates node to be manipulated

typedef struct node Node;
typedef Node *ListNode;

void ins(ListNode *ptr, char *value);
char* del(ListNode *ptr, char *value);
void prl(ListNode currPtr);
void pst(ListNode currPtr);
//function prototype

int count_of_nodes;

int main(void){

  ListNode startPtr = NULL; //sets List to Null value

  char com[MIN_LENGTH]; 
  char cho[MAX_LENGTH]; //declares com and cho to be within the set boundaries

  while(strcmp(com, "end") != 0){
    printf("Command? ");
    scanf("%s", &com);
    //entering 'end' as a command will cause this program to stop,

     if(strcmp(com, "ins") == 0){ 
       scanf("%s", &cho);
        ins(&startPtr, cho);
         count_of_nodes ++;
          printf("%s ", cho);
       printf("%d\n", count_of_nodes);
       //if statement for the insert command, 'ins', corresponds to ins function
       // Adds a string of your choice to the list
     }

      else if(strcmp(com, "del") == 0){
    scanf("%s", &cho);
    if(del(&startPtr, cho)){
      count_of_nodes --;
      printf("%d\n", count_of_nodes);
    }
    else{
      printf("%s not found.\n", cho);
    }
    // if statement for the delete command, 'del'
    //deletes a string of your choice from the list
      }

      else if(strcmp(com, "fde") == 0){
    // fde();
       scanf("%s", &cho);
       printf("%s\n", cho);

     //if statement for the force delete command, 'fde'
     // work in progress, should delete node, regargless of of it's count 
      }

      else if(strcmp(com, "pst") == 0){
    pst(startPtr);

    //if statement for the print stats command, 'pst'
    // allows you to see # of nodes, node with max count
    // node with min count, and average count of nodes
      }

      else if(strcmp(com, "prl") == 0){
    prl(startPtr);

    //if statement for printing the list, 'prl'
    // prints out the list as it is, shows the count of strings 
    }

      else if(strcmp(com, "pcr") == 0){
    // pcr();
       scanf("%s", &cho);
       printf("%s\n", cho);

       //if statement for print count range, 'pcr'
       //work in progress, should print nodes with a count between an interval
       // user chooses interval

    }
      else if(strcmp(com, "ppr") == 0){
    // ppr();
       scanf("%s", &cho);
       printf("%s\n", cho);

       //if statement for print prefix, 'ppr'
       //work in progress, should add count to node by entering node prefix
    }
      else if(strcmp(com, "psu") == 0){
    // psu();
       scanf("%s", &cho);
       printf("%s\n", cho);

       //if statement for print suffix, 'psu'
       //work in progress, should add count to node by entering node suffix
    }

    else if(strlen(com) >= 4 || strlen(com) < 3){
    printf("You have entered an incorrect command.\n");
    //bug checks
    }
  }
}


void ins(ListNode *ptr, char *value){
  //insert function

  ListNode newPtr;
  ListNode prevPtr;
  ListNode currPtr;
  //variables used in insert

  newPtr = (ListNode) malloc(sizeof(Node));
  //make space in the list for new node

    if(newPtr != NULL){
      if (strcmp(value, newPtr->list) == 0){
    newPtr->count++;
      } //trouble area, trying to figure out how to add to count
      else{
      memset(newPtr, 0, sizeof(Node));
      memcpy(newPtr-> list, value,strlen(value));
      //puts value into node

      newPtr->count++;
      }
      //  newPtr->list = value;
      newPtr->next = NULL;

    prevPtr = NULL;
    currPtr = *ptr;


    while(currPtr != NULL && value > currPtr-> list){
      prevPtr = currPtr;
      currPtr = currPtr->next;
    }
    if(prevPtr == NULL){
      newPtr->next = *ptr;
      *ptr = newPtr;
    }
    else{ 
      prevPtr->next = newPtr;
      newPtr->next = currPtr;
    }
    }

    else{
      printf("No memory available\n");
    }//bug checks
}
char* del(ListNode *ptr, char *value){
  //delete function

  ListNode prevPtr;
  ListNode currPtr;
  ListNode tempPtr;
  //variables used in delete

  // if(value == (*ptr)->list){
  if(0 == strcmp(value, (*ptr)->list)){
    tempPtr = *ptr;
    *ptr = (*ptr)->next;
    free(tempPtr); //fress tempPtr
    return value;
  }
  else{
    prevPtr = *ptr;
    currPtr = (*ptr)->next;

    while(currPtr != NULL && 0 != strcmp(value, currPtr->list)){
      prevPtr = currPtr;
      currPtr = currPtr->next;
    }

    if(currPtr != NULL){
      tempPtr = currPtr;
      prevPtr->next = currPtr->next;
      free(tempPtr);
      return value;
    }
  }
  return '\0';
}

void fde(){
} //work in progress, disregard

void pst(ListNode currPtr){
  //print stats function

  int total;
  float avg;
  ListNode maxP;
  ListNode minP;
  ListNode temp;
  //variables used in print stats

  if (currPtr == NULL){
    printf("The list is empty.\n"); //bug checks
  }
  else{
    temp = maxP = minP = currPtr;


  while (temp != NULL)
    {
      if (temp->count > maxP->count)
    {
      maxP = temp; //finds max value of count
    }
      else if (temp->count < minP->count)
    {
      minP = temp; //finds min value of count
    }
      total = total + temp->count;
      temp = temp->next;
    }

  }
  avg = total / (float)count_of_nodes; //finds average for node counts

  printf("Total of nodes: %d\n", count_of_nodes);
   printf("Max: %d\n", maxP->count);
     printf("Min: %d\n", minP->count);
      printf("Average: %f\n", avg);
      //prints for function
}

void prl(ListNode currPtr){

  if(currPtr == NULL){
    printf("The List is Empty.\n"); //bug checks

   }else{
     while(currPtr != NULL){    //loops through list and prints all nodes inside
       printf("%s " , currPtr->list); 
       printf("%d\n", currPtr->count);
        currPtr = currPtr->next;    
    }
   }
}

void pcr(){
} //work in progress, disregard
void ppr(){
} //work in progress, disregard
void psu(){
} //work in progress, disregard
```

Comment: In `ins`, you immediately allocate memory for a new node. You should be iterating through the existing list and looking for a node with a matching name. If one already exists, increment the count. If not, make a new node.

Comment: Could i just add a loop before the allocation of a new node, a loop that searches the list and looks for a matching node?

Answer (score 0):

> Could i just add a loop before the allocation of a new node, a loop
>   that searches the list and looks for a matching node?

Yes, you could. I recommend putting this loop in a function you can also use in `del`.

```
// search list '**ptr' in ascending order for string 'value'
// return 0 if string found in list, '*ptr' points to pointer to string's node
//       >0 if not found and '*ptr' points to node pointer where to insert
//       -1 if not found and '*ptr' points to null pointer where to append
int search(ListNode **ptr, char *value)
{
    ListNode currPtr;
    for (; currPtr = **ptr; *ptr = &currPtr->next)
    {
        int cmp = strcmp(currPtr->list, value);
        if (0 <= cmp) return cmp;
    }
    return -1;
}

void ins(ListNode *ptr, char *value)
{   //insert function
    if (search(&ptr, value) == 0)
        (*ptr)->count++;
    else
    {   //make space in the list for new node
        ListNode newPtr = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        if (newPtr == NULL)
        {  
            printf("No memory available\n");
            return;
        }

        strncpy(newPtr->list, value, sizeof newPtr->list);
        newPtr->count = 1;
        newPtr->next = *ptr;
        *ptr = newPtr;
    }
}
```